# BIOS not drawing text until moused over

Tags: bios

The initial screen on my BIOS setup screen (that is, the screen before the boot menu, not the normal boot screen) doesn't draw text or buttons until they are moused over. For text, it only seems to draw the portion the mouse cursor was over. I can work around this easily enough, but is there any way I can figure out why this is happening? The board is an ASRock Z170 Pro4S.

This does not happen on any other screen in the BIOS.

[image]

Comment: My suspicion would be that the BIOS tries to draw the data on that screen before the graphics card is ready for it and so ends up with a mostly blank screen. As a result it ends up just refreshing it under the mouse instead. Could be a firmware bug. Have you checked you have the latest BIOS for your board?